# How to ignore document 'define value name' in doxygen

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, doxygen

I have a define value called "Document_System". My problem is that I would like to ignore this define value `name(Document_System)` in generated documentation.

//macroHeader.h

```
#define Document_System
```

//myHeader.h

```
public:
/**
 * Creates new system check instance
 */
Document_System system_check();
```

Is it possible to document `system_check()` only instead of `Document_System system_check()`? I mean inside of my documentation I just want to show `system_check()`, not all.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Preprocessor part in the manual, this problem might be similar to the __declspec mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution adding /cond - /endcond.

```
/** @cond */ Document_System /** @endcond */
```